# Python: from list of tuples to dictionary of tuples

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

Say I have the following list of tuples:

```
mylist=[(459301.5857207412, 443923.4365563169),
        (462583.4152000006, 434743.87659999914),
        (464196.387177011, 442931.247071933)]
```

How could I turn it into a dictionary of tuples, where the key is the index of each tuple in the list, and the elements of the tuple in the dict are the two elements between parentheses?

The intended outcome would be:

```
mydict={0:(459301.5857207412, 443923.4365563169),
        1:(462583.4152000006, 434743.87659999914),
        2:(464196.387177011, 442931.247071933)}
```

Comment: `dict(enumerate(mylist))`

Comment: Interested to know why it got down voted.

Comment: You show no effort to solve the problem. You're basically asking people to write code for you, rather than help you fix your code.

Comment: All right then, all questions of this sort should be down voted

Comment: Well, yes, I'd agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dict comprehension:

```
 mydict = {k: v for k,v in enumerate(mylist)}
```